# Перестал работать слайдер. Предполагаю что проблемы с JS. Помогите починить

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть сайт. На нём есть вот такая страничка:
https://evroflag.by/realizovannye-proekty.html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Картинки по три в ряд - это слайдер. На самом деле в каждом ряду не три картинки, а больше.
То есть это слайдер. Раньше он работал, а сейчас нет.
Помогите узнать почему слайдеры перестали работать.
И буду благодарен, если подскажите как починить данные слайдеры.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

У вас на сайте скрипт слайдера выполняется быстрее, чем загружается библиотека JQuery. Добавьте код слайдера в файл и подключите.

Этот код добавьте в файл:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-1-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 8, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 8
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 4
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 2
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-2-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 8, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 8
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 4
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 2
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: false,
                nav: false,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-3-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 7, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 7
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 4
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 2
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-4-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-5-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-6-1690955108 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-7-1690955109 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-8-1690955109 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-9-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-10-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-11-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-12-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-13-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 3, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
    

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#vc_images-carousel-14-1690955110 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                items: 7, 
                responsive: {
                    1025: {
                        items: 7
                    },
                    769: {
                        items: 4
                    },
                    577: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    0: {
                        items: 2
                    }
                },
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                dots: true,
                nav: false,
                slideBy:  "page",
                navText:false,
                loop: false,
                onRefreshed: function() {
                    $(window).resize();
                }
            });
            $(window).resize();
        });
```

Подключите его:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="тут укажите путь к файлу" defer></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как можно удалить этот атрибут используя админ-панель Вордпресс, либо FTP? В каком файле удалить атрибут defer?

Comment: Изменил ответ, найдите файл realizovannye-proekty.html и в нём js код из ответа, этот код перенесите в другой созданный файл и подключите его внутри realizovannye-proekty.html